# Replace cur_data() with something else but not pick()

Tags: r, dplyr

I get a warning (see below) for `cur_data()` but I am not sure how to use `pick()` instead. I don't use it to access columns but to refer to the current dataset in the pipe.

You can use `tidylog::filter()` to see that 5 rows are dropped.

```r
library(dplyr)

VARS <- c("mpg", "disp")

mtcars |> 
  filter(if_all(all_of(VARS), 
   ~ .x >= min( filter(cur_data(), as.logical(am)) |> pull(.x) ))) 
# Warning message:
#   There was 1 warning in `filter()`.
# ℹ In argument `..1 = ... & ...`.
# Caused by warning:
#   ! `cur_data()` was deprecated in dplyr 1.1.0.
# ℹ Please use `pick()` instead.

mtcars |> 
  filter(if_all(all_of(VARS), 
     ~ .x >= min( filter(.data, as.logical(am)) |> pull(.x) ))) 
# fails


sessionInfo()
# R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
# Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
# Running under: macOS 13.1
# 
# Matrix products: default
# LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
# 
# locale:
#   [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
# 
# attached base packages:
#   [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
# 
# other attached packages:
#   [1] dplyr_1.0.99.9000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a single column, then we don't need `cur_data()`, just convert `am` to logical to subset (`[`) the column, get the `min`mum can check whether the column value is greater than or equal to the column value

```
library(dplyr)
out2 <- mtcars %>% 
    filter(if_all(all_of(VARS), ~ .x >= min(.x[as.logical(am)] )))
```

-checking with OP's output

```
> out1 <- mtcars |> 
+   filter(if_all(all_of(VARS), 
+    ~ .x >= min( filter(cur_data(), as.logical(am)) |> pull(.x) ))) 
> all.equal(out1, out2)
[1] TRUE
```

---

If we need to use `pick` (from the devel version of `dplyr`)

```
out3 <- mtcars |> 
  filter(if_all(all_of(VARS), 
   ~ .x >= min( filter(pick(everything()), 
     as.logical(am)) |> pull(.x) )))
```

-checking

```
> all.equal(out2, out3)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This is a great answer. I would still like to learn if there is another "data pronoun" or what that can be used instead of `cur_data()`.

Comment: @Rico you can use `pick` as `~ .x >= min(.x[as.logical(pick(am)[[1]])])`

Comment: I'm sure that works but I was asking if there's an alternative to `cur_data()`, e.g. `.data`, which doesn't seem to work. Maybe there is not.

Comment: @Rico `.data` is used a pronoun to select a single column i.e. `data[["am"]]`.  The problem you are trying to solve is just to  subset the column values in VARS based on a logical expression from am.  I am not sure why you need to go through cur_data() or pick, instead of directly using the variable.

Comment: @Rico updated with `pick` and used your approach with nested filter, though I would say it is not a direct approach

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would also recommend the subset `[` version.